# Is there a way on Python to make a matrix (in the maths sense) from a (blur) function?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, gaussianblur

Essentially, I'm trying to set up an inverse problem, of the form

```
Ax=y
```

where `A` is a matrix/operator (e.g. blurring) acting on an image `x` (which I `squeeze` to make an array) and `y` is the consequent data.

In order to blur the image, I can utilise the `gaussian_filter` function from `scipy`. However, in order to do regularisation, I would need `A` as a matrix, as mentioned (in order to transpose it, etc).

```
# import library
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from PIL import Image

# import image
img = Image.open("cameraman.jpg")
img.show()

# vectorise image
x = np.squeeze(np.asarray(img))

# Set up forward model and data, y = Ax
A = gaussian_filter(x, sigma=1) # Guassian blur
y = A(x) # data
```

The issue is of course the last line of the code, namely `A(x)`. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can rewrite the penultimate line to get `A` as a matrix?

Comment: The matrices for common convolutions like a Gaussian blur are well known.  Are you asking how to _infer_ one without such knowledge?

Comment: SciPy uses two 1D convolutions to implement this instead of using a 2D convolution, because that is faster. Do you want the 2D matrix that you could use to do this convolution, or the 1D array that SciPy actually uses? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.4/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L379